# How to find the incline of straight line between 2 given points of latitude+longitude in JAVA/Android?

Tags: java, android, math, coordinates

I want to use the equation of "straight line" with given 2 Latitude+Longitude points on a map. 
can i use the raw material of Latitude and Longitude to do the calculation like this-

```
        poly1_lngY= list.get(i).getLongitude(); // Y1 point on a line
        poly2_lngY= list.get(j).getLongitude(); // Y2 point on a line

        poly1_latX=list.get(i).getLatitude(); // X1 point on a line
        poly2_latX=list.get(j).getLatitude(); // X2 point on a line

        incline_poly= (poly2_lngY-poly1_lngY)/(poly2_latX-poly1_latX);
```

or should i use Math class? 
if i need to use the Math class, I would appreciate an answer to how to do that

Comment: Note: a line between two Lat/Lon coordinates is generally assumed to follow the curve of the earth and therefore not straight.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're suggesting is not correct at all.

Lat and lon are angles in spherical coordinate systems.  You should treat them as such.

The earth's radius is large enough and your distances small enough so that treating the earth as a plane is probably okay.  But you need to convert those points to rectangular coordinates before calculating distance.

A better solution would be to know how to calculate distance in the correct coordinate system so it's always correct.  Go look up how to do it for spherical coordinates or learn something about tensor calculus and metric tensors.

Comment: Thank you
your answer did help me to get on the right track